# how to price options in reality

Tags: options, option-pricing, stochastic-processes, finance, pricing

I'm getting to know the Black Scholes model, which apparently is no longer suitable for pricing options on the market. I would like to write a Master's thesis on option pricing but I do not know what specific topic related to option pricing may be interesting, what model are you using now. Someone will tell me what to write about? I would also like to ask for some nice articles / books that focus on option pricing and which I could use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Black-Scholes model is the most basic model and is used mainly for teaching purposes or as a starting point to more complex models.

I advise you to read about "stylized facts" which are empirical observations from markets and are not captured by Black Scholes model due to simplistic assumption. For example:

- fat-tailed and skewed distribution of returns (which violates normality assumption),
- volatility clustering (which violates homoscedasticity assumption)
- autocorrelation of returns (which violates Markov property).

There are many models which relax one or more of Black-Scholes model assumptions. For instance I am currently writing my master thesis on option pricing in GARCH models which captures volatility changing over time.

Comment: Black Schooles is definitely still the industry standard when it comes to option valuation for vanillas, not sure where you're getting the idea otherwise.